# Map node names using pugixml for different inputs

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing, pugixml

#### Problem

My program spits out XML nodes from a file using **pugixml**. This is the bit of the code which does this:

```
for (auto& ea: mapa) {
    std::cout << "Removed:" << std::endl;
    ea.second.print(std::cout);
}

for (auto& eb: mapb) {
    std::cout << "Added:" << std::endl;
    eb.second.print(std::cout);
}
```

All nodes spat out should have this format (for example filea.xml):

```
<entry>
    <id><![CDATA[9]]></id>
    <description><![CDATA[Dolce 27 Speed]]></description>
 </entry>
```

However what is spat out depends on how the input data is formatted. Sometimes the tags are called different things and I could end up with this (for example fileb.xml):

```
<entry>
    <id><![CDATA[9]]></id>
    <mycontent><![CDATA[Dolce 27 Speed]]></mycontent>
 </entry>
```

#### Possible solution

Is it possible to define non standard mappings (names of nodes) so that, no matter what the names of the nodes are on the input file, I always std:cout it in the same format (*id* and *description*)

It seems like the answer is based on this code:

```
  description = mycontent; // Define any non-standard maps
  std::cout << node.set_name("notnode");
  std::cout << ", new node name: " << node.name() << std::endl;
```

I'm new to C++ so any suggestions on how to implement this would be appreciated. I have to run this on tens of thousands of fields so performance is key.

#### Reference

https://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/modify.html
https://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/samples/modify_base.cpp

Comment: Are you basically wanting to know how a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) works?

Comment: @Galik I don't know how to approach this problem really. Each file will have different node tags which relate to the same data, so I need to defining mappings so that I know what data is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will is what you're looking for?

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "pugixml.hpp"

using namespace pugi;

int main()
{
    // tag mappings
    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagmaps
    {
          {"odd-id-tag1", "id"}
        , {"odd-id-tag2", "id"}
        , {"odd-desc-tag1", "description"}
        , {"odd-desc-tag2", "description"}
    };

    // working registers
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator found;

    // loop through the nodes n here
    for(auto&& n: nodes)
    {
        // change node name if mapping found
        if((found = tagmaps.find(n.name())) != tagmaps.end())
            n.set_name(found->second.c_str());
    }
}
```